# Let ${A}$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. For every two-dimensional vector ${v}$, there...

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, vectors

Let ${A}$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. For every two-dimensional vector ${v}$, there exists a two-dimensional vector ${w}$ such that
Aw = v.
Show that ${A}$ is invertible.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: No sorry I dont

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbf{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$. By the condition given $\exists \, \mathbf{w_1}$ and $\mathbf{w_2}$ respectively, such that $A\mathbf{w_1}=\mathbf{v_1}$ and $A\mathbf{w_2}=\mathbf{v_2}$. So
$$A\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{w_1} & \mathbf{w_2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{v_1} & \mathbf{v_2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus $A$ is invertible.

Comment: I don't exactly get what is going on. Are you multiplying w1 and w2 together in the last step? How did you get there?

Comment: @idk I constructed the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{w_1} & \mathbf{w_2}\end{bmatrix}$ with $\mathbf{w}_1$ and $\mathbf{w}_2$ as its columns. Then I am performaing simple matrix multiplication of $A$ with this matrix.

Comment: ooooh ok thanks! This is very helpful